# ajax post error: internal error 500 on post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net

I am running the script below whe a timer has run out of time, the post was working fine when i started passing the data through that is need for the final information is saved. that when got an internal error.

***JavaScript ajax call***

```
var selectedval;
            if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_0').checked == true) {
                selectedval = document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_0').value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_1').checked == true) {
                selectedval = document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_1').value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_1').checked == true) {
                selectedval = document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_1').value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_2').checked == true) {
                selectedval = document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_2').value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_3').checked == true) {
                selectedval = document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1_3').value
            }
            else {
                selectedval = '';
            }
            var qustNo = document.getElementById('ltlQuestNos').innerHTML;


`enter code here`            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: '{questNo:'+ qustNo.trim().toString()+',selectedoption:'+  selectedval.toString()+'}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "prTest.aspx/timeFinished", 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    // this displays the information so that the page can be re-directed to the results page. 
                    window.location = result.d;
                }
```

***Vb.net code.***

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function timeFinished(questNo As String, selectedoption As String) As String
        Dim objExam As New examClass()
        If selectedoption = "-1" Then
            'lblWarning.Visible = True
            'lblWarning.Text = "Please answer Question!"
        Else
            ' lblMessage.Text = "Navigation = " & Request.Form("textNav")
            objExam.answerQuestion(HttpContext.Current.Session("examid"), questNo, selectedoption, "00:00:00")
            ' lblWarning.Visible = False
            'close connection
            objExam.Dispose()
        End If
        objExam.finishTest(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session("examid").ToString()))
        objExam.Dispose()
        ' HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("ChapterTestSummary.aspx", true);

        Dim url As String = "testsummary.aspx"
        Return url
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with data part in ajax. Because, if you are building the data as string by yourself, key and value should enclosed in double quotes. Otherwise make it as an object and use `JSON.stringify()` method to make it as string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        questNo: qustNo.trim(),
        selectedoption: selectedval
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "prTest.aspx/timeFinished",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        // this displays the information so that the page can be re-directed to the results page. 
        window.location = result.d;
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect answer. all i had to do is chnage the get to a post